# How to access The Weather Company (TWC) Data using IBM Data Science Experience (DSX)

Tags: r, rstudio, data-science-experience

I'm using IBM Data Science Experience (DSX), https://datascience.ibm.com/. I use R with RStudio.

1. Is it possible to access data using R from DSX?
2. If not, any alternatives.

Comment: One of my Service Offerings in Bluemix is "Weather Company Data". The following operations, I've taken to pick up username and password.
Clicked on  service "Weather Company Data" / Clicked on three dots appeared on the right side of  "Weather Company Data" / View Docs / I've picked up username and password from here.
Is it the way?

Comment: No. You need to get the username and password from the "Service Credentials" on the left side. If you don't have any credentials, then you need to create them by clicking the "New Credential" button. Your credentials will appear then click on "View credential" and your username and password will be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a DSX account, you should also have an IBM Cloud account as well. If you add the Weather Company Data service inside IBM Cloud, you will then be given service credentials (i.e. username and password). With the credentials, you can then use the `httr` library, for example, in RStudio to make HTTP requests using the Weather Company API like:

```
library(httr)

r <- GET("https://<username>:<password>@twcservice.mybluemix.net:443/api/weather/v1/geocode/45.42/75.69/forecast/hourly/48hour.json?units=m&language=en-US")

content(r, "text")

[1] "{\"metadata\":{\"language\":\"en-US\",\"transaction_id\":\"1512488325604:776158712\",\"version\":\"1\",\"latitude\":45.42,\"longitude\":75.69,\"units\":\"m\",\"expire_time_gmt\":1512488925,\"status_code\":200},\"forecasts\":[{\"class\":\"fod_short_range_hourly\",\"expire_time_gmt\":1512488925,\"fcst_valid\":1512489600,\"fcst_valid_local\":\"2017-12-05T22:00:00+0600\",\"num\":1,\"day_ind\":\"N\",\"temp\":-5,\"dewpt\":-5,\"hi\":-5,\"wc\":-8,\"feels_like\":-8,\"icon_extd\":2600,\"wxman\":\"wx1210\",\"icon_code\":26,\"dow\":\"Tuesday\",\"phrase_12char\":\"Cloudy\",\"phrase_22char\":\"Cloudy\",\"phrase_32char\":\"Cloudy\",\"subphrase_pt1\":\"Cloudy\",\"subphrase_pt2\":\"\",\"subphrase_pt3\":\"\",\"pop\":0,\"precip_type\":\"snow\",\"qpf\":0.0,\"snow_qpf\":0.0,\"rh\":100,\"wspd\":6,\"wdir\":236,\"wdir_cardinal\":\"SW\",\"gust\":null,\"clds\":81,\"vis\":16.0,\"mslp\":1034.4,\"uv_index_raw\":0,\"uv_index\":0,\"uv_warning\":0,\"uv_desc\":\"Low\",\"golf_index\":null,\"golf_category\":\"\",\"... <truncated>
```

This will give you a 48-hour weather forecast for Ottawa, Canada.

To get a data frame of the results use something like:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

r <- GET("https://<username>:<password>@twcservice.mybluemix.net:443/api/weather/v1/geocode/45.42/75.69/forecast/hourly/48hour.json?units=m&language=en-US")

weather <- content(r, "text")

wData <- fromJSON(weather)
weatherDF <- data.frame(wData)
```

Some examples to show you how to use the Weather Company API on IBM Cloud is here https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Weather/weather_tutorials_samples.html#tutorials_samples.

Comment: Thanks. When I issue content(r, "parsed"), I receive "Error: No automatic parser available for application/octet-stream". The object r is a list of 10. Which list id in r contains forecast data.

Comment: Did you use your username and password that you got when you created a Weather Company Data service on IBM Cloud? You'd get that error if you didn't add a username and password from the Weather service into the API's URL. What you get back from the API is all forecast data. I've updated the answer to show what you'd get with "text" data.

Comment: How can I make a data frame from r?

Comment: Thanks. It works well. Is hourly the lowest level data? How can I get hourly data for a location, say, for the period 1 January 2016 to 31 November 2017?

Comment: You might want to accept the answer to your original question and open a new one for this followup question - more people will see it.